# How can I get a list of all gameobjects that have material component attached?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]

public class ChangeShaderMono : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject selectedObject;

    private List<Transform> selectedobjects;
    private GameObject selectonce;

    public void SelectedObject()
    {
        selectedObject = Selection.activeGameObject;

        if (selectonce != selectedObject)
        {
            selectedobjects = new List<Transform>();

            Transform[] allChildren = selectedObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
            foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
            {
                if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial != null)
                {
                    var mat = child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial;

                    selectedobjects.Add(child);
                }
            }
        }

        selectonce = selectedObject;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        SelectedObject();
    }
}
```

The problem is on the IF line :

```
if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial != null)
```

If a gameobject don't have a material it will throw exception on this line and will not continue.
I want to get all the children gameobjects that have material attached including the selected parent gameobject.

Comment: What exception does it throw? NullReference? If so, try `if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() != null && child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial != null)`

Answer (score 0):

- You could try with below.
- Codes will find all children recursively,

```cs
private void Find(GameObject parent, ref System.Collections.Generic.List<GameObject> result)
{
    var spriteRenderer = parent.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    var meshRenderer = parent.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    var image = parent.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>();

    if (spriteRenderer != null && spriteRenderer.material != null)
    {
        result.Add(parent.gameObject);
    }
    else if (meshRenderer != null && meshRenderer.material != null)
    {
        result.Add(parent.gameObject);
    }
    else if (image != null && image.material != null)
    {
        result.Add(parent.gameObject);
    }

    foreach (Transform child in parent.transform)
    {
        Find(child.gameObject, ref result);
    }
}

public void SelectedObject()
{
    if (UnityEditor.Selection.activeGameObject != null)
    {
        var result = new System.Collections.Generic.List<GameObject>();
        Find(UnityEditor.Selection.activeGameObject, ref result);
    }
}
```